# Determine the variance of the sum of two random variables, uniformly distributed in the range from $3$ to $9$.

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Determine the variance of the sum of two random independent variables, uniformly distributed in the range from $3$ to $9$.

I have no ideas, can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean uniformly distributed on the interval $[3,9]$ or uniformly distributed on the integers $\{3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$?

Comment: Are they independent? If so, variance of the sum is the sum  of the variances. If not, there is no answer to this question.

Comment: @Math1000: Yes.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: Yep, they independent.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent $\mathrm{Unif}(3,9)$ random variables and denote $Z=X+Y$. Then 
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \frac{9+3}2 = 6,
$$
$$
\mathbb E[X^2] = \int_3^9 \frac16x^2\ \mathsf dx = \frac1{18}(729-27) = 39,
$$
so $$\operatorname{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2 = 39 - 6^2 = 3.$$
Since the variance of the sum of uncorrelated random variables is the sum of their variances, we have
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) = \operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(Y) = 3+3 = 6.
$$

Comment: $\frac{9-3}{2}\neq 6$.

Comment: @NCh Thanks for pointing out the error. I have corrected it.

Comment: Next error. $\mathbb E[X]\neq \frac{9-3}{2}$. Moreover, $\mathbb E[X]=3$ can be only in degenerate case since $\mathbb P(X\geq 3)=1$.

Comment: @NCh Thanks for catching my errors; I seem to be off my game today.